# JavaScript general object throwing bad value

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask about some thing because I'm confused. I have this object:

```
        var BonusesObject = {
            priceTotal: 0,
            bonusCheckboxClick: function(){
                var price = 5;
                this.priceTotal = price;
                console.log("works, " + this.priceTotal);
            },
            getPrice: function(){
                return this.priceTotal;
            },
            init: function(){
                $('input:checkbox').on('click', this.bonusCheckboxClick);
            }
        };

        BonusesObject.init();
//now when I will fire on click event and BonusesObject.getPrice 
it will give me 0 instead of 5.
```

And now when I call BonusesObject.getPrice it will give me 0, as it should. Now when I manualy call BonusesObject.bonusCheckboxClick and BonusesObject.getPrice it will give ma 5, as it should. BUT when function bonusCheckboxClick will be called through on('click', this.bonusCheckboxClick) it will throw in console corret value 5 BUT after then when I will call BonusesObject.getPrice it still give me 0.

I would like to ask about some thing because I'm confused. I have this object:
Did I miss something? It only doesn't work when object function is fire by on click event.

Could someone explain me that ? I will appreciate that.

Comment: Probably because `this` refers to different things when called manually vs `onClick` - you can bind the click as: `this.bonusCheckboxClick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the function to the object:

`.on('click', this.bonusCheckboxClick.bind(this));`

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind